# Sending emails from .Net core 2.0 with MailKit

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am receiving this error:

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xxx.xx.xx:25

Any ideas?

Note: The credentials are good. 
Also, if I use MailKit with .net core 1.0 its working just fine but the project needs upgrading to .net 2.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

The account is the same. What I noticed is that I get the same error message if I put bogus credentials instead of good ones.
It's the credentials that are not passed the right way. But I cannot explain why the same code is working in the .Net Core 1.0 project. Regarding the code used is just a simple call to smtp server from MailKit samples

```
`client.LocalDomain = _domain;
 client.Connect(_smtpServer, 25, SecureSocketOptions.None);
 client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
 client.Authenticate(credentials);
 client.Send(Message);`
```

Comment: If your intention was to add more information to a question is it best to edit the question by clicking the edit link at the bottom of the question.